# Are agile processes taking too much time in a sprint?

Tags: management, software-development, project-management, time-management, agile

The agile processes are focused on increasing velocity but at the same time seem to require lengthy meetings.
Assuming a 2 week sprint, if I understand correctly, at the very minimum there must be:
a) a review of the sprint progress at the middle of the sprint which I would guess it is on the 5th day
b) a retro of the sprint at the end of the sprint
c) a sprint planning also at the end of the sprint to plan for the next one
d) a meeting to do some "filtering" of the items to include in the planning

These seem a lot and time consuming. So I was wondering is there a time duration or other guidance on how to do all these meetings/planning to get the most of the team's time during a sprint?

Comment: This likely is more suited for: https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: there are some advises for timing based on the size of your sprint, I usually consider at least 10% of sprint time for all ceremonies. You might encounter some opposition from devs, or even management, who prefer to spend time on "tangible" things, or delivery, but please push them back. If ceremonies seems to be a waste of time, don't abandon ceremonies, make them more valuable!

Comment: @LaurentS.: For a 2 week sprint, 10% is 8 hours. That is a full day only for meetings. That seems a lot to justify especially if I am not sure what does "make them more valuable" look like

Comment: Here is not the place to discuss agile best practices. Indeed "justifying" this time is something that may not be easy in a workplace transitioning to agile. The thing is you have to understand this is time invested, not just spent or even less wasted. Delaying a project for whatever reason (and it happens a lot...) also costs a lot of money, and unfortunately people often ask less question about that because they're so used to it. When asked to justify for that investment in ceremonies, I usually ask for an estimation of the costs incurred by delays in the previous waterfall projects...

Comment: An example of reading on the topic, but there are many similar entries or even books on the topic: https://www.scrum.org/resources/blog/scrum-myths-scrum-meeting-heavy

Comment: Worth pointing out that words like "sprint" aren't "agile processes" but specifically "scrum processes", and Scrum does talk about how much time you should spend.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as Tymoteusz Paul says, this is a software project management question, not a workplace one.

Comment: God forbid you spend any time planning your work, I’m sure working on random stuff you vaguely understand in unclear order works out great for you.

Comment: @mxyzplk-SEstopbeingevil: I agree 100% with the way you phrase it. But the issue is not about if planning is necessary but if 40% of the time period that is meant for deliverables is justified just for planning and ensuring progress is made

Comment: Sounds more like 4 hours out of 80 to me, which is not usually 40%.

Answer (score 2):

You probably aren't spending too much time in meetings, unless your meetings aren't timeboxed and made efficient.

I'll use Scrum as an example since it's more prescriptive about the duration of its events. 4 events happen with a Sprint - Sprint Planning, Daily Scrum, Sprint Review, and Sprint Retrospective. The Sprint Planning is, at most, 8 hours for a 1-month Sprint, but is often (but not necessarily) shorter for shorter Sprints. The Daily Scrum is 15 minutes per day. The Sprint Review is 4 hours long for a 1-month Sprint and may be shorter for shorter Sprints. The Sprint Retrospective is 3 hours for a 1-month Sprint and is often (but not always) shorter for shorter Sprints.

Assuming that each event is the maximum duration, that's a total of 17.5 hours in a 2-week Sprint. This means that about 22% of the time in a Sprint is spent in events, in the worst-case scenario. It may be slightly shorter since, depending on when the Sprint Planning, Sprint Review, and Sprint Retrospective fall, you may not have Daily Scrums on those days.

Scrum also calls for Product Backlog Refinement, which the team uses to understand the work closer to the top of the Product Backlog and prepare it for upcoming Sprints. This isn't timeboxed, but the guidance suggests that 10% of the Development Team's time is spent on refinement. This doesn't necessarily mean in a room in a meeting - it could be reading and thinking, it could be exploring parts of the product to understand the current state, it could be researching user needs and talking to stakeholders, it could be reading about new technologies and prototyping. When this is added in, the total time pre-allocated to Scrum's activities is about 35%.

All of this leaves 65% of the time in a Sprint, perhaps more, available for doing the work. Of course, not all of that 65% will be valuable work. There's almost always overhead - company-wide meetings, 1-1s with managers, internal training, equipment maintenance. However, there are ways to reduce some of this overhead. One common example is that meetings for the Scrum Team members can often be replaced with other communication methods, including pairing with the existing Scrum events.

I'd point out that these are the rules of Scrum. If you're using a different methodology, there may be different guidance out there. But this is a good starting point for talking about the meetings and work that needs to happen during an iteration to support agility.

Comment: `All of this leaves 65% of the time in a Sprint, perhaps more, available for doing the work. Of course, not all of that 65% will be valuable work.` so the team has max of 65% of the sprint for the deliverables. Does that mean the the planning is done including the fact that a 2-week sprint means from the 80 hours only ~50 will be used for the deliverables?

Comment: @Jim Yes. The planning needs to consider the regular stuff that happens in the iteration timebox and planned irregular stuff like holidays and vacations. Depending on the risk tolerance of the organization, there should be some consideration for unplanned events as well, to leave work for things like illness or unplanned work to arrive - there may be historical data available for this over time.

Comment: `meetings aren't timeboxed and made efficient` how would you determine the efficiency of these meetings?

Comment: @Jim Do they start promptly on-time? Are they achieving their objective within the timebox? Is everyone clear on the results and decisions made?